# Is it possible to make a turing machine counter for decimal numbers?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm solving a complex task using turing machines. To solve it, my idea was to use a turing machine, that would count decimal numbers, one digit per one place on the tape (# 1 #, # 2  #, ..., # 9 9 #, ...) . But as my knowledge of turing machines is limited, I can't figure out how it could do it or if it's even possible.

So my question is: Is it possible? If so, could you provide just a basic idea of how it'd work? Thanks!

Comment: I'd classify this as an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @KennyLau I know how to solve my problem X in other ways. Using this turing machine counter would be another solution. I just don't know if such a turing machine can be created. I can delete the first sentence of my question if it's a problem.

Comment: Is [this](http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/wyttfchoer) what you are looking for?

Comment: It rejects if there is input `9`, `99` etc. But yes, if it accepted this, it would be it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. [Fixed](http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/dsfmahwaqe).

Comment: Thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can describe a generic TM counter $M_b = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_\text{goto end}, B, F)$ for a base $b \geq 1$ with

- $\Sigma = \{0, \ldots, b-1\}$ for $b \geq 2$ and $\Sigma = \{1\}$ for $b = 1$
- $\Gamma = \Sigma \cup \{B\}$
- $Q = \{q_\text{goto end}, q_\text{inc}, q_\text{done}\}$
- $F = \{q_\text{done}\}$
- and $\delta$ as follows

  - Go to the right end
    $\forall a\in\Sigma: \delta(q_\text{goto end}, a) = (q_\text{goto end}, a, R)$
    $\delta(q_\text{goto end}, B) = (q_\text{inc}, B, L)$
  - Increment the digit

    - For $b \geq 2$:
      $\forall d\in\Sigma\setminus\{b-1\}: \delta(q_\text{inc}, d) = (q_\text{done}, d+1, N)$
      $\delta(q_\text{inc}, b-1) = (q_\text{inc}, 0, L)$
    - For $b = 1$:
      $\delta(q_\text{inc}, 1) = (q_\text{inc}, 1, L)$
    - For both, add a new digit in case we reached the left end:
      $\delta(q_\text{inc}, B) = (q_\text{done}, 1, N)$